# CodeCoverage of C++ libraries doesn't highlight all lines

Tags: c++, code-coverage

I have a C++ library which I'm instrumenting using vsinstr.exe and then running vsperfmon.exe. When I open the .coverage file in Visual Studio I am seeing some lines which are not highlighted in any color, and I know for sure that these lines were hit. What could be the reason for this? This doesn't happen when I run the same for C# libraries. It doesn't help that I'm a total newbie in C++, but I have lines with simple code not showing as hit, such as a declaration of a new variable or calls to other methods.

Comment: Are you sure the given code lines are generating code that was necessarily executed and *not* optimized away by the compiler or LTCG ?

Comment: @WhozCraig How can I tell whether the code was optimized away? I wasn't kidding when I said I'm a newbie :-) Let's say I have 2 calls to the same method, the first one is not highlighted and the second one is. What could make these calls different? I tried to compile with the /OPT:NOREF option but I got the same results.

Comment: @Josh: You could look at the assembly code (or disassembly), or you could debug and see whether the debugger skips over that line.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for that, indeed while debugging those lines that are not highlighted are skipped too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you run a binary code instrumenter, it can't instrument code that isn't there.  So optimized-away code, even if logically executed, can't be seen by a binary instrumenter.**

If you instrument the *source*, then even if the compiler optimizes "away" certain code, the *instrumentation* (having a side effect) doesn't get optimized away.  The logically executed code still vanishes from the object file, but when it would get executed, the instrumentation for that code will still exist and get executed.  So you get instrumentation signalling, that indicates that optimized code, was actually "executed" in effect.

This happens because  source instrumentation takes advantage of the compiler and how it must preserve behaviour while optimzing.  Here's another example of this:

```
         for (i=0;i<1000000;i++)
         {  executed[5923]=true;
            <body>
         }
```

What is shown is *instrumented* code.  The "executed[k]=true;" is the probe (for the "kth" chunk of program code) that says the loop body got executed. A binary instrumenter might do the equivalent of this in the object code.   Now when the loop runs, the probe gets executed on every iteration.  If this is a critical loop, performance gets affected, so instrumentatino can affect timing behavior, sometimes badly. (We note the instrumented object code is thrown away).

With source instrumentation, you get this source text. (Just like the object code case, you don't keep this, you just compile and run it, and then throw away the instrumented source code.)   The difference is the optimizing compiler recognizes the probe as having a loop-invariant effect, and rewrites the object like this:

```
         executed[5923]=true;
         for (i=0;i<1000000;i++)
         {  <body>
         }
```

The cost of the instrumentation has effectively gone to zero.  So source code instrumentation gives execution times which are much closer to the uninstrumented program.

Of course, if you test the un-optimized program, then presumably you don't care about the extra overhead for either binary or source instrumentation. And in that case, even a binary instrumenter will show that code that (could have been but) was not optimized as having been executed, if it is executed.

Our [Test Coverage tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage) do source instrumentation for many languages, including C++ (and even for Visual C++ dialects, including C++14).   It will show you that optimized-away code as covered. You don't need to do anything special to get the "right" answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, I appreciate it! I don't think I understand the paragraph before last tho, what do you mean by testing the un-optimized program?

Comment: Most compilers have switches to control the level of optimization of your code.  When you run tests, do (should?) you run them with the code compiled as production, or for testing?   Depending on what you do, your code being tested may be optimized or not.

Comment: Ah ok, I get what you mean. I did notice more lines being highlighted when compiling in debug mode as opposed to release (I'm using Visual Studio), so I guess that explains it.

Comment: Yep.  Source instrumentation wins in the face of optimization.